# ordered probit regression with only categorical variables

Tags: regression, modeling, probit, ordered-probit

I would like to know if it makes sense to run an ordered probit regression (dependent variable is ordinal with three outcomes) with only categorical explanatory variables (some are dichotomous e.g. gender; others are categories that have been entered as dummy variables e.g age).

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason why you couldn't.

Comment: Why not? It should work just like it would with any other form of regression.

Answer (score 1):

(Partially answered in comments, summarized below)

Like in about any kind of regression model, you can use any kind of variables as predictors. Categorical variables cannot be used *directly*, they must be encoded, but you can do that in **exactly** the same way you use for linear regression. So just go ahead!